# Varying amount of fields in Razor page form, returns null properties in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I've come up with problem, when trying to fill data to my model. I have an "Resource" entity, which can have no-to-many "attributes". I have templates set up, which holds names for those attributes. When Resource is created, user chooses on of templates, then Attributes are created(empty) and program generates form for those attributes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })       
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Resource)
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Attributes.Count(); i++)
        {
        <div class="form-group">
            @*Html.LabelFor(d => d.Attributes.ToArray()[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <h4>@Html.Raw(Model.Attributes.ToList()[i].Name)</h4>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Attributes.ToList()[i].Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Attributes.ToList()[i].Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This form uses this View model:

```
public class ResourceAttributesViewModel
{
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<_Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

problem is that when i hit "submit" button, it gives me view model with null Resource and Attributes properties

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Fill(ResourceAttributesViewModel AttributeSet)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var attr in AttributeSet.Attributes)
            {
                db.Entry(attr).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(AttributeSet);
    }
```

if it helps, there is POST string sent by browser

```
__RequestVerificationToken=XoVM9h_3njX5x2m35b_vKKHY3m5UDaYm9_2ZMfNkglouqHJCSw2NO56Tv2Sb3kXy8qC8XBLXawoQv0ft0xc-LxYmQGfi4EAqroq2b63Wb9Q1&Resource=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Resource_7639327FA0332BEBC7FB6836F70C3D62C3D744D76F2C3F8DDFCE679AA8CA31DC&%5B0%5D.Value=100&%5B1%5D.Value=200
```

Comment: `Attributes` needs to be `List<_Attribute>` and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attributes[i].Value, ...)` (look at the html your currently generating - the `name` attributes have no relationship to your model). And a view model should never contain properties which are data models when editing.

Comment: Note also `@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Resource)` will not work (again look at the html it generates to understand why that will not bind), but since you not even editing any properties of `Resource`, it should not be included away (just its `ID` property)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. That fixed the issue. Also your tips are very helpful. I have got ridden of Resource in model view completely, since its ID is already stored in Attribute. I have also added few `@Html.Hidden` for Attribute properties to carry over some of its data.

Comment: Generally you should not be generating hidden inputs for properties you not editing. You model should be `public class ResourceAttributesVM` with `int ResourceID` (hidden input) and `List<AttributeVM> Attributes` where `AttributeVM` contains only the properties you need for editing (and an ID property if you editing existing data). You then map the view model to the data model(s) in the POST method